# How to change UITextView last entered text color in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, text, uitextview, textcolor

I have an UITextView for entering the comments for the photos. When the user enters their text in UITextView the entered last text should be in Dark gray color other texts should be in normal color. Once the user entered Space the last entered word/text should change to black(normal) color.

```
UITextView text eg: iPhone is an apple product. Product should be in Dark gray color others in black color. Once user enter space the all entire words in black color.
```

How can i detect the last entered word and how can i change the particular last entered word text color?

EDITED :

I am trying this source code.

```
-(void) textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
   NSArray *lastTextArray = [textView.text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

   lastStringInTextView = [lastTextArray objectAtIndex:lastTextArray.count - 1];
   NSLog(@"LastText : %@", lastStringInTopTextView);

   textView.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
}
```

Comment: Anyone have any idea? Please help on my question. Thanks.

Comment: Onee more question: will this comments be displayed on UIWebView or just UIPhoto ect..?

Comment: @ilhançetin Thanks. Just i placed UITextView in an UIViewController. That's all my friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to define a listener(from the text field you entered) and it will look for a white space character(mean `' '`) in your text enter. The text color&type can be somethink like `yourTextField.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:24]` untill the listener detects a space, and when it detects the space must change to normal(and the new string must get started be typed as `yourTextField.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:24]` ...) 
Note: This is may be not a true aproach to start answering with **I think..** but you have asked for any idea. I hope this helps

**EDIT:**  This needs a good algorithm, also using blocks in the same method which will do this work. The algorithm must be designed in order to accept any `'  '` character as the beginning of text field.

Comment: If yo need more help please either share some code or ask us to help you as a beginner

Comment: The real problem here is that you need to set the text color only for a part of the text in the textView. The other part should be left black.

Comment: This needs a good algorithm, also using blocks in a method. The algorithm must be designed in order to accept any ' ' character as the beginning of text field.

Comment: I get entered last text in UITextView. But, if i change the color textView.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor]; the whole text color changed to orangeColor. But, i want to change the color to last entered word. Can you please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please share your code which does this work? I have not so much time at  the moment but if i see your code i can add what i talk about

Comment: @Gopinath ,I have some works to do now a few haurs later i will turn you back. I took a look at it but couldn't design the algorithm properly. But I will solve this

Answer (score 0):

You can use these delegate methods

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView;
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView;
```

You can then check for individual words as ilhan pointed out in the previous answer.
As for colored text, i am not sure but i think you've to write a custom class to change text color.I hope it helps.

Comment: please see my edit. these methods can be used inside the algorith directly.

Comment: I get entered last text in UITextView. But, if i change the color textView.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor]; the whole text color changed to orangeColor. But, i want to change the color to last entered word. Can you please help me. Thanks.