# Coloring the text while the user types it (iOS, Xcode)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitextview, text-coloring

I am writing an iOS iPhone app and try to add the following functionality:

- The user types a text on the keyboard.
- While he types, the text appears on the screen, but every letter is in a different color

The UIViewText API says:

*"This class does not support multiple styles for text. The font, color, and text alignment attributes you specify **always apply to the entire contents of the text view.** To display more complex styling in your application, you need to use a **UIWebView** object and render your content using HTML."*

How can I do that?

Similar question I found here, but it didn't get a conclusive answer.
[How to change UITextView last entered text color in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208488/how-to-change-uitextview-last-entered-text-color-in-iphone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITextView` does not support mixed fonts, colors or sizes. To do this you may want to check out this framework.

[OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel)

This will allow you to use `NSAttributedStrings` in a single label. Then all you need to do is load a couple `UIColor`'s into an array and randomly pick one.

Comment: Thanks! It sounds like exactly what I was looking for !